# What is the format of the time field in this cypher?

Tags: neo4j, graphaware

### Heading ##CALL ga.timetree.single({time: 1463659567468, create: true})

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree
https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/08/20/graphaware-neo4j-timetree.html

The above link says that time is in long format YYYYMMDDHHmmss. But the time parameter doesn't make any sense and random nodes are getting generated in neo4j. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfJxN.png)

What does the time parameter hold and what is the meaning of it?

Comment: having your code shown will be easier for people to figure out what you are doing, not just generic image and a link.  
what do you expect? Why do you expect something like that?

Comment: @InverseFalcon That really helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time parameter is a millisecond timestamp, or milliseconds elapsed since the [UNIX epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which is an extremely common means of storing time-related data, you can find this in use in nearly every digital system.

The timestamp cited here represents "2016-05-19 12:06:07". The timetree built starts from a root (this is a modeling convenience), and then its child is the year (2016) followed by the month (5), then the date of the month (19). Looks like it didn't automatically create any nodes for time resolutions beyond that.

Keep in mind that now that Neo4j has [native temporal values](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/temporal/) that you can use in Cypher and store as properties (as well as index), time trees are going to be less useful, as you can always do index lookups on indexed temporal properties.

There are still some cases where time trees can still be very useful, however, such as when you're searching for events that happened within some unit of time that disregards its parent units...such as finding events that happened on Mondays regardless of month, or on Januaries regardless of year, and so forth.